# Position absolute sets search result on top of one another

Tags: css, next.js

[image]

So instead of displaying items below one another, it dipslays it on top of each other.

```
.map((val, key) => {
                  return (
                      <div className="search-result" key={key}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col md="auto">
                          <img
                          onClick={() => clickProductDetail(val)}
                            src={val.images[0].src}
                            alt={val.images[0].alt}
                            width="18"
                            height="18"
                          />
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="10">
                            <div className="product-card-title">
                              {val.title}
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-card-price">
                              ${val.price}
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                      </div>
```

and the css

```
.search-result {
  // make it display on top of other elements and not push them down
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  .result{
    position: relative;
  }
  
}
```

I'm using next js, so the searchbar is part of one component whilst below it (the grey colors) is also another component. Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of giving absolute to each search result, wrap all search result in div container and make container absolute.

Comment: @Sameer tried that. still same results

Comment: @Sameer it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="search-overlay">
        {data ? (
          searchTerm !== "" &&
          data.products.items
            .filter((val) => {
              return val.title
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
            })
            .map((val, key) => {
              return (
                <div key={key}>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="auto">
                      <img
                        onClick={() => clickProductDetail(val)}
                        src={val.images[0].src}
                        alt={val.images[0].alt}
                        width="18"
                        height="18"
                      />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="10">
                      <div className="product-card-title">{val.title}</div>
                      <div className="product-card-price">${val.price}</div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
              );
            })
        ) : (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        )}
        </div>
```

moved search-overlay class which has position:absolute property up a few elements.